# no load the information whe i open a window, vaadin and java

Tags: java, vaadin

Well, I will try to explain the problem as well as possible.
I'm using vaadin 8 and I'm using java. I'm doing an app like Youtube.
First Of All I have two important class for the problem. 1º user_header. 2º main_user_page.

On the first class (1º). I have some code integrated with components vaadin that creates a header for youtube with An image and nickname.

```
public class Zona_de_busqueda_UR extends Zona_de_busqueda_UR_ventana {

public Zona_de_busqueda_UR() {

imagenCabeceraURZ.setSource(new ExternalResource(parametros.getMiniaturaUsuarioNavega()));
apodoCabeceraURZ.setCaption(parametros.getApodoUsuarioNavega());
}
```

The two atributtes are components vaadin, and I'm setting the text to show on the app.

On the second class (2º). is one page, where (after I initiate session) I can see a normal page with videos and the header of the class (1º). THIS CLASS IS WHAT I RUN AND THIS CLASS CALL THE OTHER WHERE THE ATRIBUTTES ARE EJECUTED.

```
public class Pagina_inicio_UR extends Pagina_inicio_UR_ventana implements View {

Zona_de_busqueda_UR cabeceraZUR = new Zona_de_busqueda_UR();

public Pagina_inicio_UR() {
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(cabeceraZUR);
}
```

In this class, only call the other class what you can see.

The problem is that the value of the components is showing where I refresh the app, but this would be after I initiate session. I show an example with photos.

First Of all, I initiate session. 
  ![a busy cat(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmr779/images/master/primero.PNG)

And then, The header is without information...
![a busy cat(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmr779/images/master/segundo.PNG)

Now, I click F5 on my browser or refresh the page and I can see the information but I want see the information without having to click F5 or refresh.
![a busy cat(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmr779/images/master/tercero.PNG)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are these methods all called synchonous, or have you somewhere threads or other background execution tasks?

Comment: The scheme is the next.  First of all, I load the init page where I call the header while I build the page. On the header, the builder init the atributes of the class parameters and this class obtains the atributes before all the process when I init session (here I call the data base and I get the name of parameters)

So, I dont use threads or tasks